# Analog pins giving off the same value

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sensors, code-review

So recently I made code that used two custom sensors that are connected to the analog pin A0 & A5. Schematic can be seen here (http://inmoov.fr/test-your-finger-sensor/).

```
const int ono = A0;
const int twe = A5;

int one;
int two;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  }

void loop() {
  one = analogRead(ono);
  two = analogRead(twe);

  Serial.print(one);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(two);

}
```

So after I follow the schematic i did the code, but the data value from the Serial Plotter of both sensors are always equal even though I was only pressing down on one sensor. So is this a code problem or the circuit? if so is there any fix for it? Thx.

[image: The circuit that I made is like this, the sensor is NOT an FSR it is just used to represent since its a custom sensor, look at the link for more detail]

[image: This is what the values look like, so when sensor red is pressed it will rise and blue following behind but slightly lower, and when blue is pressed blue will rise and red slightly lower]

[image: third image]

Comment: Try using `pinMode(one, INPUT);` and `pinMode(two, INPUT);` in `setup()`

Comment: Ok ill try that, ill get back to you in a bit

Comment: Could you show us some of those values?

Comment: It sounds like a circuit problem. Care to share *your* circuit, not a link to some circuit you *think* you made?

Comment: Ok i edited my post

Comment: @PurnawanBrillian This connection is wrong. You havecto connect it like resistor voltage divider.

Comment: how many Ohms do you recommend? I did try 1K and 10K it still doesnt work, look at image 3

Comment: @PurnawanBrillian It's good to use +- similar resistivity as sensor has.

Comment: @Matej yup I did try that did a 220 Ohm resistor on both the - and +, still didnt work

Comment: I also did try changing my arduino and my breadboard and the problem still occurs, so it should not be any hardware problems

Comment: When the sensor isn't a FSR, what is it?